# How to display Picklist Label, instead of Picklist API in a Formula Field

Tags: formula, formula-field, picklist

I think the title says it all, we are using picklist values having different Label and API Name. How can I display the Picklist label instead of API in when using a formula field. I know I can use IF statements and ISPICKVAL but is there a more dynamic solution, so that when new picklist values are added no need to edit the formula again.

Sample Picklist Values

---

Small Business - SAP_A

Medium Business - SAP_B

Comment: Can you post some of picklist values ?

Comment: @PrabhatKumar edited

Comment: I worked and then realized the miss. On searching this is what I found out in idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E6BtQAK. Normally we use, TEXT(PicklistField)/ IF() statements to get what you are asking for

Comment: Does this answers this ask?

Answer (score 18):

Unfortunately this feature does not seem to exist yet. Vote for this Idea:

> ## [Allow Picklist Value Labels in Formulas](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E6BtQAK)
>
> Spring '17 brought "API Names" to picklist values so that integrations can use a "hidden" value (the API name) while users can see a local or more friendly value (the label).
>
> [image: Picklist Edit]
>
> However, there isn't a way to access the label in formulas.
>
> [image: Formula Options]
>
> So, if you want a formula to display the picklist's value somewhere else in Salesforce, only the API name will appear.
>
> [image: Formula Output]
>
> This will be confusing to users if you actually have different values for API name and label, as they may not be familiar with the API name. We need a way to access the value's label in formulas. SOQL has a toLabel() function, and we need its equivalent in formulas as well.

Comment: Upvoted that idea (which everyone considers like a bug)